# How can get current date as 2021-12-30T18:30:00.000z this format in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime

I have tried like  var str=new Date(); var dt= new Date(str).toISOString(); console.log(dt);     but it's shows 2021-12-30T18:30:00.000z. please can anyone help me to solve this.thanks in advance.

Comment: Sry it shows 2021-12-31T05:44:06.792z

Comment: I expect like this 2021-12-30T18:30:00.000z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were going for a string with no seconds and milliseconds, use [setSeconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setSeconds) on Date:

```
var str = new Date().setSeconds(0,0);
var dt = new Date(str).toISOString(); 
console.log(dt);
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) it's wrking

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer, please consider accepting it. Thanks!